# I need to parse through a string and pull out information to input into a database

Tags: java, parsing, edi

here is the edifile:
ISA*00*          *00*          *02*HMES           *ZZ*MGLYNNCO *120321*1220*U*00401*000015676*0*P*:~GS*FA*HMES*MGLYNNCO*20120321*1220*15691*X*004010~ST*997*000015730~AK1*SM*18292~AK2*204*182920001~AK5*A~AK9*A*1*1*1~SE*6*000015730~GE*1*15691~IEA*1*000015676~

IN JAVA

I have an EDI file that I need to parse through.  I can get the file and I have converted it to a string and used tokenizer to break it apart, the issue I am unsure of is that there is another delimiter for each segment how can I break it apart at the segment delimiter?

```
public class EdiParserP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //retrieves the file to be read     
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        int ch;
        StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
        FileReader fileInSt = null;

        try{
            fileInSt = new FileReader(file);

            while ((ch = fileInSt.read()) != -1)strContent.append((char)ch);
            fileInSt.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("file" + file.getAbsolutePath()+ "could not be found");
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("problem reading the file" + ioe);
        }
        System.out.println("File contents:" + "\n" + strContent + "\n");//used to check to see if file is there
        System.out.print("Length of file" +" " + strContent.length()+ "\n"+ "\n");//used to count the length of the file
        String buffFile = strContent.toString();//used to convert bufferstring to string

        //breaks apart the file with the given delimiter
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(buffFile , "*");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String s =st.nextToken();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess then my second question is how to retrieve the information to put into a database, I do know how to connect to the database, and how to insert, i think, i just am unsure how to pull the data out of this string?  thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you can use a ready-made EDI parser such as http://edireader.sourceforge.net/ ? Anyway you will need to use a specification of the string to parse it properly.

Comment: Why can't you do a string.split on the tokens that contain additional delimiters?

Comment: I know about the ediparsers, but I am trying to understand how they work before I begin to use them.

Comment: I believe I am going to try string.split.  I am new to Java and I have been learning all sorts of new things. I am also new to programming so each day is a learning experience.

Comment: i used the split method, how can i use it again to separate the second delimiter?

Comment: There are three delimiters in ANSI X12: segment, element and subelement.  The segment delimiter will always be in position 106 of the ISA segment.  The element delimiter will always be in position 3.  The subelement will always be position 105.  As you read in the file, you can do a string split for the elements, and should be able to do a string split on the segment.  So read in the file, look at those positions, and then split accordingly.  You are reinventing the wheel quite a bit though.  Plenty of tools out there that will do this for you.

Comment: I have found the tools, but I am starting new at a company and this is an assignment for me to work on my java skills and introducing me to edi.  I can use split if I know the delimiter, what i am trying to do now is to do it dynamically, I can pull out the delimiter and use it in tokenization, but what I have doesnt work with split.

Comment: got the delimiter to work in a split string, thanks for the ideas and insights, im getting closer to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it won't help you to the end, but using a StringTokenizer class is rather deprecated, you should use simple split() method of String class.

To be honest, I don't know what you really want to do with that file. Do you want to split each string received from StringTokenizer class once again?

Comment: What I really would like to do is to split the file apart to be able to grab specific parts to put them into a database.  I searched and tried tokenization first, but am willing to try anything.

Comment: Which part of that file do you want to grab?

Comment: i am trying to grab each segment of the edi file to put into a database

Comment: Andrew answered you, sorry but I am not familiar with EDI file format and he is - based on his asnwer.

Comment: that is all good, i was just stuck on some ideas and i have gotten it all to work so far, truly thanks for the input any little thing helps